# Trying to show number of recursive calls for fibonacci is equal to Big O

Tags: big-o, fibonacci

I have this code to calculate the number of recursive calls and show that it's approximately equal to O(2^n) as is well known for fibonacci;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int c=0;

int fib(int n) {
    c++;
    if (0 == n) { return 0;}
    if (2 >= n) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    for(i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        c=0;
        int f=fib(i);
        printf("fib(%d) = %d,\tc = %d,\t2^%d = %f\n", i, f, c, i, pow(2,i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here's the output;

```
fib(1) = 1,     c = 1,  2^1 = 2.000000
fib(2) = 1,     c = 1,  2^2 = 4.000000
fib(3) = 2,     c = 3,  2^3 = 8.000000
fib(4) = 3,     c = 5,  2^4 = 16.000000
fib(5) = 5,     c = 9,  2^5 = 32.000000
fib(6) = 8,     c = 15, 2^6 = 64.000000
fib(7) = 13,    c = 25, 2^7 = 128.000000
fib(8) = 21,    c = 41, 2^8 = 256.000000
fib(9) = 34,    c = 67, 2^9 = 512.000000
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: It seems correct to me.  What makes you ask "what's wrong"?

Comment: If you are referring to the appended `.000000` this is due to the `pow()` method returning a floating-point value automatically printed with six trailing digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are wondering why your values for `c` and the corresponding value `2ⁿ` are not as close as you expected.

The reason for this is, that the call tree is not balanced and so `O(2ⁿ)` is just a loose upper bound. The number of calls has a lower bound of `Ω(2n/2)`.

[image: Call tree]

As you can see in the picture: The number you calculated for `n=6` is correct. You can also see that the call tree is not balanced.